# Optimizing allocation algorithm needed

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Today I encountered an interesting problem when accounting for the travel costs of my last journey with my friends.

Let's assume we had the following expenditures:

```
# expenditures in US-$
Peter= 117
Joe=    38
Bill=   15
Chris=   0
Alan=  209
Tim=   201
Ahmet= 124
Pati=   57
Steven= 74
```

Now we have decided that everybody should pay the same amount of money. Given that the average expenditure was 92.77778 US-$, The Balances look like this:

```
# balances in US-$
Peter=  24.22 
Joe=   -54.78 
Bill=  -77.78
Chris= -92.78
Alan=  116.22
Tim=   108.22
Ahmet=  31.22
Pati=  -35.78
Steven=-18.78
```

So now I would like to find an optimization method where we have a minimum number of total bank-transactions and a fairly distributed share of transactions over all participants (so two optimization aims)

I have looked up the [Stable Marriage Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) but I think it doesn't apply in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a difficult problem -- sort the participants by ascending expenditures, then, in that order, have each participant transfer their negated (current) balance to the next participant. n-1 transactions, and at most one transaction per participant. Each of which, of course, is the best you can do in general.

Or is there some extra constraint I'm missing?

Comment: Beat me to it :). +1. I'd only add, that this solution does not take under consideration, that often when you chip-in for something, you pay an amount that is a multiplication of 10, or 5. In this special case you can achieve better result than n-1, because for example 2 transactions from 2 other people may cover both their positive, and your negative balance.

Comment: Consider there are 2*5=10 people. 5 of them each has -1 balance, 5 of them each has +1 balance. The optimum number of transaction is 5. How would your algorithm work?

Comment: That's what I mean about the "general case". In the example given, there's no way to go below n-1 transactions. If that is what Joschi was looking for, though, I think there's a pretty straightforward way to do that. (Basically, a variation on the dynamic programming algorithm for subset sum.)

Comment: makes totally sense. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This method only solves the part of "minimum number of total bank-transactions".

People are grouped into two categories, say `Giver` (whose balance is negative) and `Receiver`(whose balance is positive).

**Key Observation** In an optimum solution, a giver should always give away money, a receiver should always receive money. It's impossible for person A gives money to B and then B gives some money to C.

Now comes the solution.

```
While (there is some giver or receiver) {
    Find the giver with the largest balance, say A.
    Find the receiver with the largest balance, say B.
    Let A gives as much money as B needs.
    Delete Person if his/her balance becomes 0.
}
```